# Group String Concatenation: which approach, if any, is any more guaranteed?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Itzik Ben-Gan explains in his book 'Inside Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008: T-SQL' how **Appoach A** works, because of the undocumented behavior of SQL Server in which it performs assignment for each result record from the `SELECT`.

A well respected collegue and DB guru has suggested that **Approach B** *is* guaranteed to work. His argument is based on the recursive nature of `COALESCE` versus the 'values expansion' method of `CAST`.

Actually, I have no idea what 'values expansion' refers to (except for the fact that it is casting one value to another) or how it applies to this problem? Perhaps he misunderstood? Yes `COALESCE` is recursive in a sense, but as far as I can see it is irrelevant and the desired result is produced because of the undocumented behavior of multiple assignment.

Is he correct? Please, no "Use `FOR XML PATH` instead" answers!

**Approach A**

```
DECLARE @output VARCHAR(100);
SET @output = ''; 

SELECT @output = @output + CAST(COL_VCHAR AS VARCHAR(10)) + ';' 
FROM someTable;
```

**Approach B**

```
DECLARE @output VARCHAR(100);
SELECT @output = COALESCE(@output + ', ', '') + COL_VCHAR  
from someTable;
```

Comment: @Adrian They both work. Question is not if they work, but if I am correct in saying that they both work because of the *same undocumented behavior*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a conforming SQL implementation could evaluate all of the output rows simultaneously, in parallel, neither is *guaranteed* to work. That they *happen* to work, today, is an artifact of the current SQL Server implementation.

Your colleague is incorrect to assert that `COALESCE` somehow changes the processing model.

I.e. a conforming implementation could effectively hand each potential row in the result set (having evaluated `FROM` and `WHERE`) to a separate thread, that then performs whatever processing is required in the `SELECT` clause (before presumably recombining results in order to assess `GROUP BY`, `HAVING` and `ORDER BY`).

There are no standard requirements governing access to variables during such processing, so each thread could "see" the same initial value of `@output` (`NULL` or `''`, depending on which form you're using), perform it's own update calculation, and assign that result value to `@output` - the final value of `@output` might then any of the individual row results - or anything else for that matter.

Answer (score 4):

I believe they both work because of the same underlying (and undocumented) behavior. I am fairly confident that if you take a case where Itzik has demonstrated that **Approach A** fails, that **Approach B** will also fail in the same way and for the same reasons, in spite of your colleague's claims. I don't see how

```
DECLARE @output VARCHAR(100);
SELECT @output = COALESCE(@output + ', ', '') + COL_VCHAR
```

Is any different from:

```
DECLARE @output VARCHAR(100) = '';
SELECT @output = @output + ', ' + COL_VCHAR
-- or SELECT @output += ',' + COL_VCHAR
```

So what exactly does `COALESCE` magically introduce? SQL Server isn't going to change its plan because of something you're doing to the output, AFAIK.

I use them all the time for dynamic SQL generation and don't recall ever seeing them fail, and I realize that's not your question. Unfortunately there isn't really a way to prove it unless you know of a case that fails for either approach.

I wrote a blog post about string concatenation a few months ago. It's not completely relevant to your problem but Rob Farley made a comment that may be considered another downside to the `COALESCE` approach:

https://sqlblog.org/2011/03/08/t-sql-tuesday-16-this-is-not-the-aggregate-youre-looking-for

Comment: Thanks for your input. The concern is relying on an undocumented behavior/feature in a massive production system. Some hotfix down the road, microsoft decides to do things different behind the scenes and this no longer works and breaks things.

Comment: Both *can* fail if if you want a specific order of the concatenated values. Not the case here but if you do, `for xml` is the way to go.

Comment: If your concern is forward compatibility then I would say both approaches introduce the same level of risk. With that in mind `FOR XML` is, as @Mikael suggests for other reasons, probably the most future-proof method. I realize that's not what you want to hear, but better safe than sorry. It's quite easy to encapsulate this kind of thing - how many different queries are you doing this concatenation for? If it is a lot then perhaps the data model should be a more important concern.

Comment: I read your article - you sure would be the right guy to answer this question! Yes, I thought `FOR XML` would be the safe, supported way to go. Actually, Ben-Gan suggests this method in his book. As far as the data model, the data is pulled this way for presentational purposes a good bit - but not my call

Comment: @J Cooper one other comment. If guaranteeing future compatibility (or order) is paramount to strict performance, use a cursor. Anything else is an undocumented trick.

Comment: @AaronBertrand You mention that you "don't recall ever seeing them fail". Just so you're aware for future use, Microsoft documented this [variable-based concatenation method failing](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287515) when used with a function in an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @Riley Quite aware of that KB (and still don't think the behavior would differ whether using `COALESCE` or not). I never use this methodology when I absolutely need to rely on order anyway; if I care about order, I use `FOR XML PATH`. Some recent posts: http://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation http://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation-2 http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/grouped-concatenation-use-cases/

Comment: @AaronBertrand It's not just order, though; it outright swallows up one of the items. I found that KB when I encountered the situation in the wild in production. We were gathering up a list of notes to display to the user, and one of them was just gone. But anyway I agree that `COALESCE` is not relevant to the KB (unless you apply it in the ORDER BY, as applying any function in the ORDER BY appears to be the cause).

Answer (score 0):

In your example, there is a way to get different results, and that is if NULL values are introduced into the data set.  e.g.:

```
set nocount on

declare @test table (value int)

insert into @test values (10)
insert into @test values (20)
insert into @test values (null)
insert into @test values (40)
insert into @test values (50)

DECLARE @output VARCHAR(max);

-- Approach A
SET @output = ''; 

SELECT @output = @output + CAST(value AS VARCHAR(10)) + ';' 
FROM @test

print 'Result from A:'
print isnull(@output, '{null}')

-- Approach B
set @output = ''
SELECT @output = COALESCE(@output + ', ', '') + cast(value as varchar(10))
from @test

print 'Result from B:'
print isnull(@output, '{null}')

set nocount off
```

Approach A will return null, whereas Approach B will return `40, 50`

Answer (score 0):

They work differently, the first example adds an additional character to the end of the output variable, and yes they work because of the same behaviour.

The first example will work if your column had been a numeric or date also. It would however only take the first 10 characters of any value in the column. The second example would not cut off the column.

There is absolutely no recursive nature of COALESCE.
COALESCE is a way of replacing null values with replacement values.

EDIT:

I should add that i also prefer the second version, because you don't get that extra semicolon, in the end of output implying that more values will follow.